# Retrieve access_token from cookie for Azure AD Passport BearerStrategy

Tags: adal

I have a webapp which uses OIDCStrategy to authenticate the user. It uses cookies instead of sessions with the `useCookieInsteadOfSession` flag. My other app is an API protected by BearerStrategy. My webapp, using axios `withCredentials: true` I'm sending over the browser cookie. But at the API, the BearerStrategy only checks the request header for Authorization. Is there any way to extract the access_token in the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand (of the technology and from your question) you need to use an Auth library like Passport-Azure-Ad for javascript.